# Can the spatial structure of a string theory string be observed?

Tags: string-theory

I understand that, today, the length of a string is too small to be observable. But if technology were not a problem, would we be able to observe the shape of the string, the motion of its ends, its shape? or are these properties in principle not observable, and we are limited to only observing things that look like particles?

Comment: This might not answer your question about observability, but the perspective might be useful: [Size and shape of strings](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/SIZE-AND-SHAPE-OF-STRINGS-Karliner-Klebanov/d730404f308c003c4494cbce595036e9859cf027) by Karliner, Klebanov, and Susskind (1988). Also section 4 in [arXiv:hep-th/9308139](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9308139). The paper [Measuring the size and shape of strings](https://inspirehep.net/literature/297276) might be interesting, too, but I haven't read that one; I just happened to notice the title.

Comment: Also, for perspective: as far as I know, *none* of the proposed nonperturbative formulations of string theory refer to strings at all. Examples include the BFSS Matrix theory (for asymptotically flat spacetime) and the AdS/CFT correspondence (for asymptotically AdS spacetime). But I don't know what this says about the observability of the strings that gave perturbative string theory its name. Nonperturbative formulations of quantum field theory are formulated in terms of fields, not particles, but many QFTs still predict observable particles.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Thanks! I will read those references